# Add maven project to Dynamic Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I currently have an opensource maven project that I have downloaded off github. The project includes 14 modules, all having dependencies with each other.

I am trying to create a RESTfull API using Tomcat 9 on eclipse to access the aforementioned project.

I started by creating a dynamic web application in eclipse. Is there any way I can add the project (GitHub project mentioned above) to the dynamic web application, so I can write a logic layer that can interact with the project.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal for your second project is to consume the RESTful web services exposed by the first, then it doesn't need to actually interact with the first project at the code level. I would just create an entirely separate project in Eclipse. The first REST project you downloaded doesn't even need to be running on the same machine as your second project.

Comment: This first project is not a REST project, it is a local maven project. What I wanted to do is create a REST Api to interact with the first local maven project. Therefore, I wanted to take the jar files from the local project and say how interact with them on the REST Api that I want to build

Comment: I think there is some confusion here.  The REST API project can be accessed basically from everywhere: a browser, SOAP UI, or another web application.  The REST project can and arguably should be separate from the other project IMO.